# How to add on click information on places in any layers in OpenGeo Suit 4.5?

Tags: layers, boundless-suite

I recently installed OpenGeoSuite 4.5 and I am very new in to it. I uploaded my .shp file in it and it showing that layer currently. Now I want to add some information(name and a little info etc) of those places . Which i want to show by clicking on that particular place like state or  building etc. Can I also add markers and images on my map? So please give me steps to do it.